# C++ lambda - capture member variable

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I have a class that has function pointer to kernel function, that can change from outside.

```
class Bar 
{
   public:
     int i;
}

class Foo 
{
   public:
     std::function<double()> kernel;
     Bar bar;         
};

int main()
{

  Foo f;
  f.kernel = []() -> double { return i * i; }; //this is not working obviously

}
```

How can I achieve behaviour that is "presented", eg. read class variables inside lambda. I can bypass it by passing `f` inside and write `f.bar.i`, but that is not very nice solution.

Comment: What's wrong with `[&f]() { return f.i * f.i; }`?

Comment: @KerrekSB I have edited the question

Comment: So you basically want to call `f.kernel()` and `kernel` should automatically be bound to `f` like it was a member function?

Comment: @dhke yes.. basically that is what I want

Comment: Why isn't it just a member-function then?

Comment: @NaCl I need to dynamicly change the function from outside

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In C++14 you can write it as,

```
f.kernel = [&i = f.bar.i]() -> double { return i * i; };
```

If you don't have C++14, you can alternatively create another variable,

```
int &i = f.bar.i;
f.kernel = [&i]() -> double { return i*i; };
```

Though there's nothing wrong with passing `f` and writing `f.bar.i`.

Comment: Nice. But this binds the kernel lambda to that particular instance of `f`, doesn't it? Hence if I do `f2.kernel = f.kernel` and call `f2.kernel()` I get the `i` from `f`? Might not be a problem, though.

Comment: just an FYI compiling the first example with g++ -std=c++11 gives `warning: lambda capture initializers only available with -std=c++14 or -std=gnu++14` so it is a C++ 14 feature

Comment: @NathanOliver Removed the "believe". @dhke Yes, if you copy the `kernel` from `f` to `f2` then you'd be using the same function if you call it from either instance.

Answer (score 8):

It seems that [you cannot do so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11901084/pass-lambda-expression-as-member-function-pointer-in-c). 
There is no construct to create a member function lambda.

But you probably can follow @KerrekSB's suggestion and in addition to that dispatch the call to still get the member function:

```
class Foo 
{
public:
    double kernel()
    {
        _kernel(*this);
    }

    std::function<double(Foo &)> _kernel;
};


Foo f;
f._kernel = [](Foo &f) -> double { return f.i * f.i; };
f.kernel()
```

Note that you cannot name both fields `kernel`.

Comment: I like this solution too. You could also make `_kernel` static so that all instances would share the same "member function".

Answer (score 0):

The lambda function does not know about i or Bar. How could it know? You need to pass a Reference. If you define the function body differently so you can pass i as parameter and you call it within the class you should get what you want.